# How to save created Zip file to file system in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, zip

Using python zipfile module I created a zip file as follows:

```
s = StringIO()
zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(s, "w")
zip_file.write('/local/my_files/my_file.txt')
s.seek(0)
```

and now, I want this `zip_file` to be saved in my file system at path `/local/my_files/` as `my_file.zip`. 
Generally to save a noraml files I used the following flow:

```
with open(dest_file, 'w') as out_file:
    for line in in_file:
        out_file.write(line)
```

But, I think I can't achieve saving a zipfile with this. Can any one please help me in getting this done.

Answer (score 8):

```
zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile("/local/my_files/my_file.zip", "w")
zip_file.write('/local/my_files/my_file.txt')
zip_file.close()
```

The first argument of the `ZipFile` object initialization is the path to which you want to save the zip file.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to use StringIO, just try this code:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import zipfile

s = StringIO()
with zipfile.ZipFile(s, "w", compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
    zf.write('/local/my_files/my_file.txt')

with open('/local/my_files/my_file.zip', 'wb') as f_out:
    f_out.write(s.getvalue())
```

Or you can do it in a simpler way:

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile("/local/my_files/my_file.zip", "w", compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
    zf.write("/local/my_files/my_file.txt")
```